# Is CoreOS affected by CVE-2016-8655?

Tags: linux, security, coreos

I'm struggling to figure out whether CoreOS if affected by [CVE-2016-8655](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q4/607) or not - it was disclosed to the public on the 6th of December 2016.

The latest [stable release](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5gqzk0/race_condition_in_linux_kernel_allows_privilege/) is 4.7.3 and according to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5gqzk0/race_condition_in_linux_kernel_allows_privilege/) that should be affected as I can't find any statement from CoreOS. Reading the [CVE](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q4/607) there's a paragraph

> I found the bug by reading code paths that have been opened up by the
>   emergence of unprivileged namespaces, something I think should be
>   off by default in all Linux distributions given its history of
>   security vulnerabilities.

Are unprivileged namespaces enabled in CoreOS? (and would that make sense when you run everything in containers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a community manager for CoreOS. The lead on our OS team confirmed we're affected, and in the process of releasing an update right now.

You can keep your eyes glued to [releases](https://coreos.com/releases/), if you'd like to track the update.

Cheers,